# Manually label in Task package

Tags: formatting, tasks

I want to manually label inside the `\task` environment. For example (a) and (b) are subquestions of 1 so I want to label them (1a) and (1b) respectively. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\linespread{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{\large Math 194 Tutorial 7 Solution}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{Excercise} }
\end{center}

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$ \\
\task $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$ \\
\task $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$ \\
\task $(a+5b)(12x+3)$ \\
\task $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1) $ \\
\task $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you had a look at page 11 of the manual?

Comment: Are you merely referring to the typeset appearance in the question of `a) (2z - 13)(5x + 4y)`, or are you referring to the notion of `\label`ing the task so that you can later `\ref`er to it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I have attached a picture which explains what I require. Sorry if that was not clear in my initial explanation

Comment: If you only need the alternate label on some of the labels, using the optional argument, `\task[1a)] ...` should do it.  However, you probably need to expand the label width as well, as clemens describes in his answer.Note though, that using the optional argument will destroy the ability to employ `\label` `\ref` mechanism, unless alternate steps are taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### manual labels

You can always use the optional argument to `\task` which of course is error-prone:

```
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task[1a)] $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$ \\
  \task[1b)] $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$ \\
  \task[2)] $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$ \\
  \task[3a)] $(a+5b)(12x+3)$ \\
  \task[3b)] $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1) $ \\
  \task[4)] $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$
\end{tasks}
```

[image]

`tasks` does not really support this in an automated way.

#### original answer

Is this what you want? I introduce a new counter `question` and then set up `tasks` this way:

```
\settasks{
  counter-format = (\thequestion tsk[a]) ,
  label-width = 2em
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\linespread{2}

\settasks{
  counter-format = (\thequestion tsk[a]) ,
  label-width = 2em
}

\newcounter{question}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \underline{\textbf{\large Math 194 Tutorial 7 Solution}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \refstepcounter{question}
  \underline{\textbf{Question \thequestion} }
\end{center}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$ \\
  \task $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$ \\
  \task $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$ \\
  \task $(a+5b)(12x+3)$ \\
  \task $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1) $ \\
  \task $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I require something like that but I have edited my question a bit to reflect what I intended to ask. I have included a picture of what I require. I'm not sure if `\task` is the correct way to do something like this? I just want the columns to be spaced out as is but I want to add the counters manually. is that possible?

Comment: @RMaharaj well, a manual solution is always possible, see my edited answer